# what's wrong with my media CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got this in my .css file...

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
    .mt-5-xs {  margin-top: 5px; }
    .mt-10-xs {  margin-top: 10px; }
    .mb-5-xs { margin-bottom: 5px; }
    .mb-10-xs {  margin-bottom: 10px; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {  
    .mt-5-sm { margin-top: 5px; }
    .mt-10-sm { margin-top: 10px; }
    .mb-5-sm {  margin-bottom: 5px; }
    .mb-10-sm { margin-bottom: 10px; }
}
```

And then this in the HTML:

```html
<div class="mt-5-xs mt-5-sm">
    <button ...></button>
</div>
```

However, the `margin-top` does not render on small screens. And when I look at the Styles in dev tools, they don't even show up. It's like the classes don't exist in the css. I know the html page has access to the overall .css file, because it's where every other class is, and they all work fine.

I'm doing something wrong, just not sure what.

Comment: Do you have "class=" in your HTML div?

Comment: yeah, that was a copy paste error.  Fixed in the OP

Comment: Did you mean `@media (max-width: 576px)`? You say small screens, but none of your media queries would affect anything below 576px.

Comment: As @disinfor says, you are not setting any style below 576px

Comment: As this appears to have been a typo between `min` and `max`, this question is [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic) and should be closed as such.

Comment: @zzzzBov at least wait until OP replies before flagging for closing.

Comment: @disinfor, _or_ I could expect OP to [invest more time into researching their own problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418) before posting and wasting everyone else's time.

Comment: Not a typo.  At least not in terms of Min and Max.  The missing class=" WAS a typo, but has been fixed in the OP/

Comment: @zzzzBov I agree that if it is a typo (@Casey - min/max still falls in the realm of typos), it should be closed. I was only giving caution if changing the `min` to `max` wasn't the issue at hand (even though I think that's the case).

Comment: Not a typo. I just didn't fully understand how min an max worked.  Had them reversed in my head.  Feel free to close if you think it's best.  Or (to help other people down the road) someone could post the correct answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your posted codes, your HTML code has the issue not the CSS as your must add class="" attribute to your div

```
<div class="mt-5-xs mt-5-sm">
    <button ...></button>
</div>
```

Update : also as already other persons mentioned, if you are checking below 576px then you should add a `@media (max-width:575px)` or maybe 576px too.

Comment: oh, that's a copy paste problem, Lemme fix that

Comment: Please don't use answers to point out typos. Use comments. If it turns out that was the problem, the question should be closed.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is, if you are checking below 576px then add @media (max-width:575px) as well

Answer (score 0):

Try `@media only screen and (min-width: 576px)`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Just to be clear, do I actually put `@media only screen and (min-width: 576px)` in the .css file?

Comment: Yes @CaseyCrookston, you do; and same for (min-width: 768px).

Comment: Same result.  (Not sure who down voted you.  Wasn't me.)

Comment: Check the comments on your question; they are right; try using max-width.